# Drupal Commerce eBay-style listing upgrades

Tags: drupal-7, e-commerce

I'm creating a Drupal 7 module which allows users to post free adverts. I would like to add some paid listing upgrade options (bold text, images, etc) but am unsure how to achieve this with Drupal Commerce. Any suggestions?